# How to get data from a Row when i have one Field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database i'm accessing in a Java Servlet and i have the columns (ID, NAME, LAT, LONG). I have the name of a location but need to get the rest of the data. I'm using this SQL command to get the data.

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE NAME = London
```

However i get this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: London)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `single-quotes` around a constant value. Or it would be interpreted as a column.

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE NAME = 'London'
```